# Converting BNF to EBNF confused about the difference between left and right recursion

Tags: regex, bnf, ebnf

I have this BNF rule:

```
<S> ->  <A> b | <A> b <C>
<A> ->  a | a <A>
<C> ->  c | <C> c
```

i want to turn it into EBNF rule however i am confused about the left and right recursion in the `<A> and <C>`, how will it differs in EBNF or they will be the same?

Here is what i did:

```
To convert: <S> -> <A> b | <A> b <C> to EBNF
1.   <S> -> <A> b | <A> b <C>
2.   <S> -> <A> b [<C>]
3.   <S> -> <A> b (<C>)?
To convert: <A> - >  a | a<A>  to EBNF
1.  <A> - >  a | a<A>  
2.  < A> - >  a | a{a}
3.  < A> - >  a | a{a}+    
4.  <A>  - > a+
To convert: <C> -> c | <C> c to EBNF
1.  <C> -> c | <C> c
2.  <C> -> c | {c} c
3.  <C> -> c | {c}+ c
4.  <C> -> c+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They'll be the same.  For example, `<C>` will match all of the following:

```
c
c c
c c c
c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c c
```

And `<A>` will match all of the following:

```
a
a a
a a a
a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a a
```

As a result, the EBNF for both will match.  In general, if the left recursion is at the very beginning and the right recursion is at the very end, they will look similar:

```
<A> -> a | a <A>
<C> -> c | <L> c

EBNF:
<A> -> a | a a*
<A> -> a+
<C> -> c | c* c
<C> -> c+
```

What this EBNF grammar doesn't express is how the expression is parsed.  In converting from BNF to EBNF, you lose the expressiveness.  However, you can make it explicit by avoiding `+`:

```
<A> -> a a*
<C> -> c* c
```

Of course, the fact that both reduce to `E+` means you can parse them as left-recursive or right-recursive, and the result won't matter.  That's not always true—`(2-3)-4 ≠ 2-(3-4)`—but you do have the option of converting `<C>` to a right-recursive production, and the result will be the same.